# django-rest-auth error - save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using django-rest-auth with a custom user model, registration view and serializer. What I'm trying to achieve is an email login instead of username. The api view shows correctly but when I post, I get the error:

```
TypeError at /rest-auth/registration/
save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

this is the traceback: http://dpaste.com/2FR3DZY

serializer.py

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Serializer for User objects."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password')
        extra_kwargs ={'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new User."""

        user = models.User(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'] 
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

views.py

```
class CustomRegistrationsView(RegisterView):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer
```

urls.py

```
path('rest-auth/registration/', CustomRegistrationsView.as_view(), name='rest_register'),   
path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
```

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
"""Helps Django work with our custom user model."""

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        """Creates a new user object."""

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address.')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        """Creates and saves a new superuser with given details."""

        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True

        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Represents a "user" inside our system."""

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        """Used to get a users full name."""

        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Used to get a users short name."""

        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """Django uses this when it needs to convert the object to a string"""

        return self.email
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Can you paste your models, it looks like the save() method in models is overwrited

Comment: Added my model to the original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because your custom registration view inherits from `RegisterView`,`perform_create` method define in `RegisterView` will call your serializer's save method with a request object based on the [implementation](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/views.py#L72) and since your serializer inherits from `ModelSerializer`, the save method does not take any positional argument hence the error.

`CustomUserSerializer` needs to define a save method that takes the request object as an argument. Check this exempt below from [django-rest-auth configuration](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

> The custom REGISTER_SERIALIZER must define a def save(self, request) method that returns a user model instance.

I'll suggest you take a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py#L166) of the default REGISTER_SERIALIZER it'll guide how your custom serializer should look.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is this:

django-rest-auth implements custom `RegisterSerializer` where the save method takes one additional  positional argument request.

```
  def save(self, request):
```

This serializer is used by RegisterView from djang-rest-auth.

Normal serializer save method looks like this:

```
  def save(self, **kwargs):
```

You use your custom serializer in your view which parent is django-rest-auth `RegisterView` but your save method does not have the positional request argument, hence the problem.

And the logic in RegisterView assumes correct serializer implementation.

Try to use RegisterSerializer as parent to your serializer - you just need to investigate if it is straigtforward or you need to add/implement something else.

But it might be bit tricky.

But as it seems, you have custom model, custom serializer, custom view - i dont see any reason to use django-rest-auth RegisterView. Just implement your registration view.

Comment: Thanks django-rest-auth seems like it's more trouble then it's worth if you want to change anything. I wanted to use it as I'm new to Django and don't know how to do email confirmations and I thought I could save some time but it looks like I need to learn how to do that and not use this package since the amount of time spent to figure the customisation is as much as doing it myself

Comment: Your flow is quite standard way to do things, and it is not very hard to implement using just django rest framework. Email confirmations are also easy with one additional view. if you decide to use django-rest-auth, it might help you of course but perhaps better without custom modifications.