# i need help overriding user registration field in django rest auth package

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

My custom user model requires the `full_name` `email` and `password` in order to authenticate and the Django rest auth displays only fields for username email and two passwords fields. I was able to override it by declaring my own serializer and it worked. But I get this error saying:

> save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
{
    "username": "",
    "email": "",
    "password1": "",
    "password2": ""
}
```

> save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>
> Exception Location:    C:\Users\zeus\Desktop\alihub-back\env\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\registration\views.py in perform_create, line 73

Comment: Please share your code and exact error stacktrace.

Comment: Did you override the `create` method for Serializer? If so, please share that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532288/django-rest-auth-error-save-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given)

If the problem not solved. Add what you try

Comment: i could not override the create method.. please show me h